# How can we make disabled radio button in bold letters in orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I am using orbeon 3.9 CE version.I 've a scenario like to disable a radio button while selecting other. While doing, the disabled one goes to dull grey color.I want to make this dullable to normal one.

For ex, While selecting male radio button,female radio button is disabled. But its going to dullable grey color. i want this to be like a normal font.

Is there any solution to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're talking of read-only radio buttons. By default, they show as follows, with the first screenshot taken from Chrome and second from IE9:

[image: Read-only radio on Chrome]
[image: Read-only radio on IE9]

Both browsers make the radio buttons "grey" to indicate that they are disabled / read-only. This is standard browser behavior, and I don't think you change how browsers render disabled radio buttons in a way that works across browsers. And for reference, this is it looks when the radio are not disabled / read-only, again on Chrome and IE9:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Avernet,sorry for inconvenience.I'm talking about that label(Ex:Second choice) behind the radio button.Label "Second choice" is going to dull grey color while disabling.I want to make this label to normal font eventhough its disabled.

Comment: @Sarath I added screenshots to my answer showing the case where the control is *not* read-only, and you can see that the label color does not change whether the control is read-only or not. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I want the same(label color should not change whether the control is readonly or not) in my case.But I couldnt.Can u please share the sample code for this.Due to limitations of this site,I couldn't add screenshot.

Comment: u ve answered for my query in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753774/readonly-field-behaviour-in-orbeon-forms…. When m using xxforms:readonly-appearance it doesnt work.<xforms:bind id="activate" ref="activate" readonly="../deactivate=''" xxforms:readonly-appearance="static"/> Still m getting dullable grey color for a readonly field.Can u Please share sample code for this.

Comment: I tried it in Form Builder and its working as u mentioned above.How shall i bring this behaviour in my form which is developed by Orbeon CE